# Why can't I see my LabelFrames?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Frame

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, pixwidth, pixheight):
        self.__initialize_master(pixwidth, pixheight)
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        self.pack() 

        self.__initialize_top()

    def __initialize_master(self, width, height):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.geometry("%dx%d+100+100" % (width, height))

    def __initialize_top(self):
        self.top_frames = [tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Status"),
                       tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Graph"),
                       tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Universal Controls")]
        for i in xrange(3):
            self.top_frames[i].grid(row=0,
                                    column=2*i,
                                    rowspan=4,
                                    columnspan=2,
                                    sticky='nswe')

    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = App(800, 600)
    app.run()
```

I'm not exactly sure what I should be seeing, but I expect to at least be seeing the titles of the LabelFrames or something! But all I see is a blank window. I'm not sure why I can't see stuff, can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To display LabelFrame, you should add at least one widget to it.

```
def __initialize_top(self):
    self.top_frames = [tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Status"),
                   tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Graph"),
                   tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Universal Controls")]
    for i in xrange(3):
        self.top_frames[i].grid(row=0,
                                column=2*i,
                                rowspan=4,
                                columnspan=2,
                                sticky='nswe')
        lb = tk.Label(self.top_frames[i], text='test') # <-----
        lb.pack()
```

Comment: Ok. I will add the Labels that I am planning to put on them, and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not give your labelframes any children, and you did not specify a width and a height, the size of each frame will be 1 pixel. So, they are there on the screen, you just can't see them

If you put something in each frame, or you give them a width and a height, they will show up.